# Inverse parallelogram

Tags: java

I'm trying to make the output something like this:

[image]

I know the problem is in the third loop, but I dont know what to do to make the spacing work for this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x, y;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of stars: ");
        y = in.nextInt();

        //loop for x lines
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

            //loop for y stars
            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                System.out.print("* ");
            }

             System.out.println();

             for(int l = 0; l <= i; l--){
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what output are you currently getting?

Comment: I'm currently getting this http://prntscr.com/8zjv4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a couple things.

The first is move your last nested for loop (the one that prints spaces) to the beginning of the first for loop. You will also want to remove the space you have added to the for loop that prints the asterisks.

Then, for the output you have showed us, you need to start you main for loop at the end and go backwards.

Try the following:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of stars: ");
    int y = in.nextInt();

    //loop for x lines
    //This starts at x and goes toward 0
    for(int i = x; i > 0; i--){
        //Insert spaces based on line number
        //This is at the beginning now
        for (int s = 0; s < i; s++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        //Print y stars
        //Removed the space after the asterisk
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Tested [here](https://ideone.com/dbXSvX) and matches the output in your first image

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder your for loops. Please note the change in condition in the second for loop in given ode below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

       for(int l = 0; l <= x-i; ++l){
             System.out.print(" ");
         }

        //loop for y stars
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }

         System.out.println();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
         for (int j = x-1; j > i; j--) {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
         for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
             System.out.print("*");
         }
          System.out.println();
     }
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation so that OP understands why your solution works

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    String stars = String.format("%0" + y + "d", 0).replace('0', '*');
    for (int i=x; i > 0; i--)
    {
       System.out.println(String.format("%0$"+i+ "s", ' ')+stars);
    }
    System.out.println(stars);
```